# In powershell when I call Get-ChildItem or gci, the Mode column forces each item into 2 lines

Tags: powershell

A typical result might look something like this:

```
Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
d----     8/16/2018 11:07 AM        <DIR> .vscode
-
d----     8/16/2018 11:07 AM        <DIR> amazon-redshift-utils
-
```

I think it should look like this:

```
Mode            LastWriteTime       Length Name
----            -------------       ------ ----
d-----     8/16/2018 11:07 AM        <DIR> .vscode
d-----     8/16/2018 11:07 AM        <DIR> amazon-redshift-utils
```

This is on a new computer - I remember it happening on the old computer several years ago and I got if fixed, but I can't find a reference to it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer i found was in my profile script - i was renaming the prompt before importing posh-git

i found that this simple command had the effect but i don't know why.

```
if(Test-Path Function:\Prompt) {Rename-Item Function:\Prompt PrePoshGitPrompt -Force}  # this seems to mess up my LS.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to PS.

In general, console output will autowrap based on screen resolution or your defined console width settings.

You can also use ...

```
Format-Table -Autosize
```

... but now on wide screen output, it will list as you show, but will be truncated.

***Update for OP***

Review your console / editor settings. For example from one of my clients.

```
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI | Format-List -Property *

ForegroundColor       : DarkYellow
BackgroundColor       : DarkMagenta
CursorPosition        : 0,3
WindowPosition        : 0,0
CursorSize            : 25

BufferSize            : 180,3000
WindowSize            : 180,60
MaxWindowSize         : 180,73
MaxPhysicalWindowSize : 274,73

KeyAvailable          : False
WindowTitle           : Windows PowerShell
```

Comment: this didn't seem to have an effect on the gci command
i don't think this is an effect of the width of my screen - its not cutting the end of the line off - its the mode column which is at the front of the line.

Comment: This is something environmental on your side. Are you doing this in the consolehost, ISE or VSCode?  This is not something I've ever had happen, with the exception of the console / editor width settings not be wide enough. Change your console / editor width to say 120 via the console / editor properties window. See my settings in my update to you. Post yours.

Comment: ForegroundColor       : DarkYellow
   BackgroundColor       : DarkMagenta
   CursorPosition        : 0,69
   WindowPosition        : 0,20
   CursorSize            : 25
   BufferSize            : 120,3000
   WindowSize            : 120,50
   MaxWindowSize         : 120,72
   MaxPhysicalWindowSize : 274,72
   KeyAvailable          : False
   WindowTitle           : Powershell

Comment: using the console host....

Comment: i've changed the values of all these to more or less match yours (the widths are all 180 now) and it has no effect on the Mode column

Comment: The 120 should have been fins for this. So, very strange indeed. Do a quick check in the cmd.exe (just using dir as a sanity check) ISE and VSCode to see if you get the same thing. This is looking like the default PS formatters are borked.

Comment: ISE looks right, VS Code terminal looks the same as the console with the 2 line

Comment: Did you try both VSC terminals. The default terminal is just like the normal consolehost, the integrated terminal is closet to the ISE. You only get the ISE-like terminal if you open a script pane and set the language to PS. You could add that to your user settings so it is that way all the time. See: 
1) https://mikefrobbins.com/2017/08/24/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-and-configure-it-as-a-replacement-for-the-powershell-ise,
2 ) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-6, 3 ) https://clebam.github.io/2018/01/28/VSCode